# Updating a Record from VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, update

I have a VF page showing a list of records. One column displays the value of a checkbox on the record.

VF page snippet:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="List of Incidents">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!incidents}" var="inc"> 
            <apex:column headerValue="Do Not Anonymise">                       
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!inc.Do_Not_Anonymise__c}"/>                    
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Incident Number">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!inc.id}">{!inc.Name}</apex:outputLink>                    
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!inc.Incident_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!inc.Date_Of_Incident__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!anonymise}" value="Anonymise"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="location.reload();" value="Update List"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

My controller has a method to get the incidents to display and also to anonymise incidents.

Controller:

```
public class incidentAnonController {

public Incident__c firstDate{get; set;}
public Incident__c lastDate{get; set;}
public List<Incident__c> toUpdate = new List<Incident__c>();

public incidentAnonController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    Integer dy = System.today().day();
    Integer mo = System.today().month();
    Integer yr = System.today().year();
    firstDate = new Incident__c(Date_Of_Incident__c = Date.newInstance(yr, mo, dy).addMonths(-6));
    lastDate = new Incident__c(Date_Of_Incident__c = Date.newInstance(yr, mo, dy).addMonths(-12));  
}

//return a list of incidents to display on VF page
public List<Incident__c> getIncidents() {   
    //get list of incidents older than 6 months
    List<Incident__c> results = 
        [SELECT id, Incident_name__c, Date_of_incident__c, Name, Do_Not_Anonymise__c
         FROM Incident__c WHERE Date_of_Incident__c <= :firstDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND 
         Date_of_Incident__c >= :lastDate.Date_Of_Incident__c];

    return results;        
}          

//method to anonymise relevant records
public void anonymise() {     
    //list of incidents older than 6 months. These will be anonymised.
    List<Incident__c> results = [SELECT Id, Incident_name__c, Date_of_incident__c, Do_Not_Anonymise__c, Name, Garda_Name__c
                                 FROM Incident__c WHERE Date_of_Incident__c <= :firstDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND 
                                 Date_of_Incident__c >= :lastDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND Do_Not_Anonymise__c = FALSE];
//DO SOMETHING WITH <LIST>RESULTS
```

What I want to do is have the user be able to check the checkbox on the VF page and have this update the record before `Anonymise()` is invoked so that the record is not included in the anonymisation.

There is an `Anonymise` button on the VF page that invokes the method.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class level variable with get and set

```
List<Incident__c> incidents {get;set;}
```

Rename getIncidents() method to some other name and set incidents

```
//Set a list of incidents to display on VF page
public void getOldIncidents() {   
    //get list of incidents older than 6 months
    incidents = 
        [SELECT id, Incident_name__c, Date_of_incident__c, Name, Do_Not_Anonymise__c
         FROM Incident__c WHERE Date_of_Incident__c <= :firstDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND 
         Date_of_Incident__c >= :lastDate.Date_Of_Incident__c];

    //return incidents;        
}
```

Call this getOldIncidents() method from Constructor

```
public incidentAnonController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    Integer dy = System.today().day();
    Integer mo = System.today().month();
    Integer yr = System.today().year();
    firstDate = new Incident__c(Date_Of_Incident__c = Date.newInstance(yr, mo, dy).addMonths(-6));
    lastDate = new Incident__c(Date_Of_Incident__c = Date.newInstance(yr, mo, dy).addMonths(-12));
    incidents = new List<Incident__c>();  
    getOldIncidents();
}
```

In anonymise method, update the incidents which are displayed in visualforce page

```
//method to anonymise relevant records
public void anonymise() {
    //update all the incidents which are updated by user in the visualforce page
    update incidents;
    //list of incidents older than 6 months. These will be anonymised.
    List<Incident__c> results = [SELECT Id, Incident_name__c, Date_of_incident__c, Do_Not_Anonymise__c, Name, Garda_Name__c
                                 FROM Incident__c WHERE Date_of_Incident__c <= :firstDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND 
                                 Date_of_Incident__c >= :lastDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND Do_Not_Anonymise__c = FALSE];
//DO SOMETHING WITH <LIST>RESULTS
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I couldn't get it for ages but the mistake I made was in `getOldIncidents`I had left `List<Incidents__c> incidents = [SOQL]`when it should just have been `incidents = [SOQL]`. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's great to hear. Happy coding !!